# A bound on the squares of primes

Tags: number-theory, inequality, square-numbers

If $p_n$ is the $n$th prime, what is the best known upper bound on $m$ such that $p_n \cdot p_{m+n} < p_{n+1}^2$?

Comment: I think the problem is equivalent to bounding above$$\sup_n [\pi(p_{n+1}+g_{n}) - \pi(p_{n+1})]$$ where $g_n = p_{n+1}-p_n$.

Comment: Do you know if any finite bound exists at all? I suspect it may be unbounded.

Comment: I don't know of any bound but suspect m = phi(P_n)/2 - 1 would work where P_n = p_1p_2 ... p_n.  I was hoping for a known strong result such as m = 3.

Comment: What value of $m$ do you get for $p_n=113$? (Note; $p_{n+1}=127$)